# Mute MacBook at startup, both chime and volume

Tags: macos, boot, audio, system-sounds, macos-highsierra

I've got a MacBook Pro Mid 2014 on High Sierra and I would like to know if there is any way to mute the laptop at startup? So not only do I want the chime to be muted (there are 100x posts about this) but I want the sound to be muted at boot so I can turn it on only if its needed.

Answer (score 1):

Launch Terminal (*Macintosh HD - Applications - Utilities*), and type/paste:

- `sudo nvram SystemAudioVolume=%80`

You'll be prompted for the same password you use to log in to your Mac.

Once you do this, reboot. If it's not muted, try the same thing again but with one of the following instead:

- `sudo nvram SystemAudioVolume=%01`
- `sudo nvram SystemAudioVolume=%00`
- `sudo nvram SystemAudioVolume=" "` *(double-quote, space, double-quote)*

To undo this change, `sudo nvram -d SystemAudioVolume`.

Comment: sadly this does not work for me

Comment: @toom Try [resetting the SMC](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295) and [resetting the NVRAM](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063), then try again.

Comment: no dice, i appreciate the help tho

Answer (score 0):

Sadly the solution of Alex doesn't work for me. However I Found this tool that does the job so far:
Mutes sound at logoff and shutdown etc.

https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/35207/auto-mute#